# C# async call method periodically

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, timer

Main thread of application is doing some work.

There also exists a timer, which should every 10 minutes call some method which should run asynchronous.

Could you please give me a good example how to organize this?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET, forms, other?

Comment: It's a windows service which is actually a server and always listening for new connections. So there is not GUI, but server work shouldn't be stopped

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would not recommend using an explicit thread with a loop and sleep. It's bad practice and ugly. There are timer classes for this purpose:

If this is not a GUI app, then you can use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) to execute code on a different thread periodically.

If this is a WinForms/WPF app take a look at [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) and [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) respectively. These are handy because they execute their code on the GUI thread, thus not needing explicit `Invoke` calls.

The links also contain examples for each one.

Comment: Just a curiosity, if these timers execute on the GUI thread they will block the main application, surely a separate thread is better for the asynchronous requirement? I agree though that keeping an entire thread alive for an execution every 10 mins is not ideal though.

Comment: @Vok: It depends what you need to do. These timers are good for a quick periodic update of the GUI. If the code is more long-running, you should use the `System.Threading.Timer` with an explicit `Invoke` just for the update part. Anyway, it's good to know the tools available for different situations.

Comment: The Problem with timers is, a timer will fire, regardless if the last timer event has completed or not.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to call *one* big function which sleeps for 10 minutes between the actions. This doesn't block anything because it is in another thread.

In .NET 4, you would do this with the `Task` class:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { /* your code here */ });
// or
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(YourFunctionHere);

void YourFunction() {
    while (someCondition) {
        // do something
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
    }
}
```

(this code has not been tested)

Comment: How about replacing Threas.Sleep with wait Task.Delay() ? Besides of that the best answer I was able to find: Using tasks only and very simple.

Comment: Thanks, but when I wrote this answer, `Task.Delay` (as well as `async` and `await`) as part of .NET 4.5 wasn't available yet (only as RC). The final release was 2 months later. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a BackgroundWorker thread.

```
void FireTask()
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Your job   
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Start another thread that runs a loop

Inside the loop; sleep for 10 minutes then call your method, repeat

Comment: This approach is too expensive.